# How do you run Drush commands via crontab on Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8, drush

I am trying to execute drush commands through a crontab for a Drupal 8 site.  These commands work when I call them directly, but when run through my user's crontab I get the following error:

> \Drupal::$container is not initialized yet. \Drupal::setContainer() must be
> called with a real container.

Other posts suggest this is a bug within older versions of Drush, but I am on 10.3.5.

I have tried a number of things over the past few hours including reconfiguring cron, but ultimately it seems Drush is not bootstrapping Drupal correctly, but I need to be able to run the queue from cron

This is a test command I'm running which just adds to the Drupal log...

crontab (my user)

```
* * * * * /var/www/html/vendor/bin/drush scr /var/www/html/scripts/what.php -r /var/www/html/web
```

what.php

```
<?php
\Drupal::logger('mymod')->info("CHECKING IN FROM CRON CLI...");
```

Here is another command, closer to what I'm trying to accomplish...
crontab (my user)

```
* * * * * /var/www/html/vendor/bin/drush queue:run commerce_recurring -r /var/www/html/web >> /var/www/html/private/logs/cron_commerce_recurring.log
```

The error I get here is:

> Command queue:run was not found. Drush was unable to query the database. As
> a result, many commands are unavailable. Re-run your command with --debug
> to see relevant log messages.

I get this same error when running this command with drupal console.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: -r is shorthand for --root.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a database connectivity issue.  The tricky part was getting to the error.  I had to install an MTA, so that cron could write errors to my local user's mailbox and then add the --debug option, so that I could see the real error.

I'm working on a DDEV instance and for some reason the DDEV settings were not  being loaded.  An issue for another day...